# implement Windows timer

Tags: windows, winapi, timer, glut, freeglut

how would one implement a C++ timer function which would act like:
`void glutTimerFunc(unsigned int msecs,void (*func)(int value), value);` but was purely WinAPI (or STL) stuff? I need it to not busy wait, though. It needs to call a function after X number of milliseconds Thank you for any/all help!

I've been looking at `struct timeval tv;` but I'm al little confused about how to actually implement it. It needs to be a drop in replacement for `glutTimerFunc()`. Thanks

Comment: Is it o.k. if it calls a function in another thread? If it is, take a look at [timer queues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687003(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: I'm not sure, but It needs to update variables. I'm still learning about threads, but I am guessing that wouldn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Waitable Timers - [SetWaitableTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686289%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) after calling `CreateWaitableTimer`

> When the due time arrives, the timer is signaled and the thread that
>   set the timer calls the optional completion routine.

There is an example of what I think is your desired usage pattern [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686898%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: I think that is a busy wait, same as if I ran a delay() type of function. - just more precise.

Comment: No, that's not a busy wait.  `SleepEx` puts the thread to sleep; the kernel will wake it only when an APC arrives.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686307%28v=vs.85%29.aspx